# How deterministic is UuidCreateSequential with respect to the MAC Address?

Tags: mac-address, winapi

My understanding is that on Windows systems in XP, Vista, and Win7, and on the server products based on the same kernels, the UuidCreateSequential() Win32 API call makes use of one of the MAC addresses on the system to generate the UUID, and places that value at the tail end of the generated GUID.

My question is, given that the configuration set of network devices does not change, does UuidCreateSequential always choose the same MAC address each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot rely on the same MAC address being used.  From the [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt):

> 4.1.6.  Node
>
> For UUID version 1, the node field
>   consists of an IEEE 802 MAC 
>   address, usually the host address. 
>   For systems with multiple IEEE 802
>   addresses, any available one can be
>   used.

Comment: That's the specification. But how does the API method actually behave?

Comment: @ob - I got that reference from a user who was seeing diff values on Windows 2000 here, if I were you I would not rely on this using the same MAC each time - http://cookp.com/thread/1295588/UuidCreateSequential

Comment: I suppose this is the most I'm going to learn from this question.

Comment: @Rob - sorry there is no more definitive info

Comment: Not offended, Steve; I just hoped MS had something out that would show us how they implemented it.